# Implement drawRect: cause entire view to be updated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Recently, I use apple's Quartz Debug to detect the screen update in macOS.

As far as I know, in the NSView, the dirtyRect param in`- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect` meaning the portion on the view to be updated.

In my new created project, I create a simple "CustomView", it's implementation is quite simple, as showing below:

```
#import "CustomView.h"

@implementation CustomView

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSLog(@"dirtyRect:%@", NSStringFromRect(dirtyRect));

    [[NSColor blueColor] set];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}

@end
```

Than, I create a button:

```
- (IBAction)testButtonClick:(id)sender {
    [self.customView setNeedsDisplayInRect:NSMakeRect(1, 1, 50, 50)];
}
```

When I click the button, I have following log in my console:

```
2017-08-07 16:11:01.914859+0800 TestScreenUpdate[17818:728751] dirtyRect:{{1, 1}, {50, 50}}
```

It's quite ok.
But when I enable the Quartz Debug to detect the screen update, every time I click the button, the entire CustomView was updated.
Here is the [gif screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt0ka.gif)

Apple's [DragItemAround](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DragItemAround/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003900) project do not have this issue, it only update the dirty portion.

And my project create by Xcode 8.3.3 and do not have any special configuration.

Maybe the call stack on `drawRect:` would explain something:

Here's the call stack on `drawRect:` in my project :

```
#0  0x00000001000017d4 in -[CustomView drawRect:]
#1  0x00007fffa4073513 in -[NSView(NSInternal) _recursive:displayRectIgnoringOpacity:inGraphicsContext:CGContext:topView:shouldChangeFontReferenceColor:] ()
#2  0x00007fffa4072eb9 in __46-[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:]_block_invoke ()
#3  0x00007fffa40729e1 in -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] ()
#4  0x00007fffa40723a6 in -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) drawLayer:inContext:] ()
#5  0x00007fffabf4c5a5 in CABackingStoreUpdate_ ()
#6  0x00007fffac06b558 in ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke ()
#7  0x00007fffac06b070 in CA::Layer::display_() ()
```

And here's the call stack on `drawRect:` in apple's DragItemAround project :

```
#0  0x0000000100001007 in -[DraggableItemView drawRect:]
#1  0x00007fffa406cf99 in -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] ()
#2  0x00007fffa40bcf2f in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] ()
#3  0x00007fffa40bd39a in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] ()
#4  0x00007fffa40bd39a in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] ()
#5  0x00007fffa406aad2 in -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
#6  0x00007fffa406a2af in -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have Core Animation layers enabled for your view or one of its ancestors. I think when you update a layer, the window server sees the entire contents as being updated, even if you only redrew part of it.

The Cocoa App template in recent versions of Xcode enables layers at the root view by default. The template in older versions of Xcode did not, and many of Apple's sample projects were created using older versions of Xcode.

Select your view in your storyboard or xib. Then choose View > Utilities > Show View Effects Inspector. If “Core Animation Layer” is enabled for the view or any of its ancestors, then the view is drawn into a layer. You can try disabling it to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right. I just figure it out too after watching the [Layer-Backed Views: AppKit + Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/217/) WWDC session.